# How to change Delay in swiper in swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

I am using swiper.js for making a slideshow of images and videos. Here i want to change delay when user click on a button. But i don't know how to change delay in swiper or any other method to do it??

I have read documentation of swiper.js but there is no function to change delay after creating swiper object.

[JSFiddle(code)](https://jsfiddle.net/zLfxv45m/)

```
  <div id="swiper" class="swiper-container mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
       <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="static\images\arlens.gif" alt="ar">
            <span class="subtitle">
                Hi, Reader Thanks for reading
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next" id="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev" id="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
<div class="speed_btns" id="speed_btns">
    <button onclick="change_speed(7500)">1x</button>
    <button onclick="change_speed(5500)">2x</button>
    <button onclick="change_speed(2500)">3x</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
let speed = 2500
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        centeredSlides: true,
        autoplay: {
            delay: speed,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },

    });
   
  function change_speed(speed){
          // WANT TO CHANGE 'delay' OF 'swiper2' TO 'speed'
  }
```

Hope, you will guide me...

Comment: Do u have any jsfiddle or anything like that? That would be better for other users to work on the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One [possible approach](https://jsfiddle.net/z269dybh/), following advice given in [this issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/134):

```
function change_speed(speed){
  swiper2.params.autoplay.delay = speed;
}
```

As you store the instance of Swiper in the variable, you can use it to modify  all its settings directly. The one you need - delay - is placed in `autoplay` section, according [to docs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#autoplay).

Comment: Boom!! It works, Thanks for - your valuable time and helping me. :)